# How to make directory structure from array of JSON objects

Tags: java, json

I have an JSONArray(org.json.JSONArray) of JSONObjects(org.json.JSONObject) like

```
[
    {"id":"abc", "parent_id":""},
    {"id":"def", "parent_id":"abc"},
    {"id":"ghi", "parent_id":""},
    {"id":"jkl", "parent_id":"abc"},
    {"id":"mno", "parent_id":"ghi"},
    {"id":"mno", "parent_id":"def"},
]
```

Here "id" field represents unique id of the Object and "parent_id" represents id of it's parent. I have to convert this JSONArray into another JSONArray where I can have elements nested inside their parent(directory like structure) like

```
[
    {"id":"abc", "parent_id":"","children":[
        {"id":"def", "parent_id":"abc","children":[
            {"id":"mno", "parent_id":"def","children":[]}
        ]},
        {"id":"jkl", "parent_id":"abc","children":[]}
    ]},
    {"id":"ghi", "parent_id":"","children":[
        {"id":"mno", "parent_id":"ghi","children":[]}
    ]},
]
```

Can anybody help me here what is the best possible way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have something like this (pseudo code)

```
// Element is { id, children }
Dictionary<String, Element> elements;

for (JSONObject obj : arr) {
    if (elements.hasKey(obj.id)) {
        // Maybe you need to update your element or something here
    } else {
        // Create your element
        elements[obj.id] = new Element(obj.id);
    }

    // if the parent does not exist, create a shadow of the parent
    // (it'll get filled in with more info above if encountered later)
    if (!elements.hasKey(obj.parent)) {
        elements[obj.parent] = new Element(obj.parent);
    }

    // Add yourself to children
    elements[obj.parent].children.push(elements[obj.id]);
}

// TODO: iterate your dictionary and put it into an array, this should be straightforward
// Or if you want the root of your tree return elements[""]
```

I apologize in advance for not being more specific, but this should work pretty generically for whatever you want to do.  Also it's not Java, but easily convertible.

Comment: Thank you Anthony but your answer will work only if there is one level (parent>children) inside the hierarchy. The children may be nested up to n levels (parent>children>grand children and so on...).

Comment: This _should_ work approximately as posted.  `elements[""]` should contain the root, which will have children that point at the other elements inside `elements`.  I'll have to check my c# implementation of this when I get home (I needed to do the exact same thing except mine was folding a tree from a database)

Comment: @rahul0789: Since I don't have a way of showing it in java, here's a javascript proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/Ngd9H/1/

Comment: this code only provides two level...what if i want n level of parent-child

Comment: You'll have to clarify, as written this works for however nested you want.